# Counting Occurrences by ROW in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, rows

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      Select a BW Speed      Router Name  router_max OK or REPLACE?     Firewall Name  firewall_max OK or REPLACE?
0                     50           XYZ        30.0        REPLACE               X          30.0        REPLACE
1                     50           XYZ        30.0        REPLACE               X           NaN            N/A
2                     50           XYZ        30.0        REPLACE               X          30.0        REPLACE
```

I need an additional column that shows the number of times "REPLACE" occurs in that row (in this case it is the total number of items that need to be replaced).

Any help would be appreciated...I know this is probably pretty basic stuff.

Comment: - Instead of just an image,  please provide a proper data frame that people can work on it.
- You can also share the exact output you want that can help people understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("REPLACE").sum(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `stack` and `groupby` with `str_contains` to avoid using apply.

```
df["replace_check"] = (
    df.stack().to_frame()[0].str.contains("REPLACE").groupby(level=0).sum()
)
```

---

```
print(df)

       Select a BW Speed  Router Name   router_max OK or REPLACE?    \
0                       50         XYZ         30.0          REPLACE   
1                       50         XYZ         30.0          REPLACE   
2                       50         XYZ         30.0          REPLACE   

     Firewall Name   firewall_max  OK or REPLACE?  replace_check  
0                 X           30.0        REPLACE            2.0  
1                 X            NaN            N/A            1.0  
2                 X           30.0        REPLACE            2.0
```

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using `apply`? Is it slow or bad practice for some reason?

Comment: @FJC it's fine is there is no other option. The functions made available by the Python api are vectorised, meaning they operate in a highly efficient manner. When you use `.apply` you give that up and end up using a vanilla Python for loop which is magnitudes slower. 

It's usually considered an anti pattern.